# Sizing on Large Screens with Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-7

I have a some winform applications which lose some controls when opened on a large monitor with windows 7. I created the applications in XP initially but I when they are opened in windows 7 some of the controls vanish from the screen. I set the attribute of *FormBorderStyle to Sizable* but I was wondering if anyone had any different or long term solutions?

Comment: `long term solutions` - Yes. Forget winforms and use modern technology (XAML), which is resolution independent by default.

Comment: Just out of curiosity are your `DPI` settings normal?

Comment: It really depends on the users of the various applications...

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fc6f12e5-3184-45f5-a31c-7a0c0a13fa3c/how-can-i-make-the-windows-forms-resolution-independant-desktop-application-development-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral), [Docking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be that, what you need. I actually hadn't any problems of this matter but as an alternative, scaling the controls to a relative size may also help. See the first link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use any kind of Container controls like Panels/GroupBox  controls and properly dock your controls inside it and also containers aswell. If you have specific requirements using Anchor Property on the control also will also help.